# Internal Merge tool (merge-other) is "not found"?

Tags: mercurial, mergetool

I am merging my current working directory with another head using mercurial internal merge tool called merge-other and i am getting following error:

```
/bin/sh: internal:merge-other: command not found
```

i am running this command :

```
hg merge --tool=internal:merge-other rev
```

Comment: Error occurs if there is any conflict otherwise it's working perfectly fine. I don't understand it.

Comment: Leave out the `internal`, i.e., `hg merge --tool :merge-other`.

Comment: Leaving out "internal" is not making any difference. Still the same error.

Comment: It should at least be a *different* error...

Comment: Without "internal" it doesn't work at all. "Internal" has to be there. Wondering if i need to do any changes in hgrc.
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/merge-tools

Comment: The general idea is that when Mercurial has a problem merging some group of files on its own, it falls back to the specified tool. If the tool name starts with `:` it is internal and Mercurial looks in its table of internal tools and uses it. Otherwise it is external and Mercurial invokes the shell to run the tool. The error message you are seeing comes from Mercurial invoking an external tool. With a prefix colon, if you get any error (and in this case you shouldn't get any error at all), it will be *different* from `/bin/sh: ... not found`.

Comment: Among all the internal tools only :merge-other is not working(showing above error).Other tools are working absolutely fine with that syntax (with _internal_)

Comment: I had a look at the source code, and if you use `internal:...` Mercurial just strips off the `internal` part, leaving the `:...` part. So these should end up working the same. If `:merge-other` isn't working, it must be missing; but that seems impossible as it's just a decorated function in `filemerge.py` and *all* the internal merge functions are in that one file, https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/tip/mercurial/filemerge.py

Comment: wondering if there is any other merge tool which can work same as a :merge-other i.e. can resolve conflict automatically by taking _other_ changes.

Comment: can :other tool be used in place of :merge-other ? No , right ? because if i do i'll loose all my local changes too which i don't want. I want to keep my changes too , but while merging tool should take other branch changes instead of local's to resolve the conflict.

Comment: They have different meanings, `:other` means take the other branch changes, `:merge-other` means allow conflicts to happen (i.e., take both changes and combine them) and then if and when conflicts *do* happen, prefer the other guy's changes.

Comment: That's right.And i need to implement **:merge-other** only and only this one is not working.